# Total Variation Denoising help

Tags: self-study, optimization, numerics, noise, differential-equations

I am trying to work through the "Mathematical exposition for 1D digital signals" in the wikipedia entry for Total Variation Denoising ([TVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising#Mathematical_exposition_for_1D_digital_signals)). I am familiar with Lagrange multipliers. However, I cant understand how to differentiate $V(y)$ and $E(x,y)$ with respect to $y_n$. Could someone walk me through this? A perfect answer would provide math and code I can use to step through in a numerical example.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what you need? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Total variation is not differentiable when $y_{n+1} - y_n = 0$, because of the $\ell_1$ norm.

You will have to resort to either a subgradient method, or do a change of variables and use the soft-thresholding operator to solve the proximal problem. You can also replace the problem with a smooth approximation.

Comment: 1) Can you enlarge upon your first point? Is this because of the 'v' in the graph y = |x|? 2) Lets say the situation yn+1 - yn = 0 never occurs - i'm just trying to get a sense of how to do this

Comment: Yes, your function, $V(y)=\sum_n |y_{n+1}-y_n|$ is not differentiable, because the $\ell_1$ norm is not differentiable at zero. Its subdifferential at zero is $[-1,1]$, so you can minimise $E+\lambda V$ by a subgradient algorithm. They are generally very slow, thought, so I recommend you use the other approaches I mentioned. Don't assume a possible situation will never occur; you will be taunting Murphy ;-)